# django modelform saving issues

Tags: django, django-forms

## views.py

```
if pform.is_valid():
    user = pform.save()
```

## forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sex = forms.CharField(max_length = 20,label="I am :",widget=forms.Select(choices=SEX_CHOICES,attrs = {'class':''}),required = False)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Please enter your real name.','class':''}),required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter last name.','class':''}),required = False)
    location = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your current location','class':''}),required = False)
    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        if first_name == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return first_name
    def clean_phone(self):
        phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        if phone == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return phone

    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if last_name == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return last_name

    def clean_profession(self):
        profession = self.cleaned_data['profession']
        if profession == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select a valid option.")
        return profession

    def clean_sex(self):
        sex = self.cleaned_data['sex']
        if sex == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Select a valid option.")
        return sex

    def __init__(self,*args,**kw):
        super(UserProfileForm,self).__init__(*args,**kw)
        self.phone = self.instance.get_profile().phone
        self.profession = self.instance.get_profile().profession
        self.sex = self.instance.get_profile().sex
        self.location = self.instance.get_profile().location        

    def save(self,*args,**kw):
        self.instance.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        self.instance.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        self.instance.get_profile().sex = self.cleaned_data.get("sex")
        self.instance.get_profile().location = self.cleaned_data.get("location")
        self.instance.get_profile().profession = self.cleaned_data.get("profession")
        self.instance.get_profile().phone = self.cleaned_data.get("phone")
        self.instance.save()
        return self.instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','phone','sex','profession','location')
        #exclude = ('email')
```

## doubt

everything is working fine but y am i not able to save the information to the user profile , when i use the `self.instance.get_profile().phone = self.cleaned_data.get('#some_field')` , because when i am retrieving the data its not showing up in m form , please help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you well, then you get data from the form and can't save it to the users profile. To fix this, you need do save user profile too:

```
def save(self,*args,**kw):
    self.instance.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
    self.instance.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
    profile = self.instance.get_profile()
    profile.sex = self.cleaned_data.get("sex")
    profile.location = self.cleaned_data.get("location")
    profile.profession = self.cleaned_data.get("profession")
    profile.phone = self.cleaned_data.get("phone")
    profile.save()
    self.instance.save()
    return self.instance
```

Comment: but still when i am promting user for the edit form the profile data is not there(phone , sex , profession , location) , only the firstname and lastname is visible , is there anything wrong with my __init__ method??

Comment: You shouldn't use init method- just use 'initial' argument when you [construct the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a `#` when fetching the field.  Do this instead:

```
self.cleaned_data.get('some_field')
```

Comment: i used that just to mention that #some_field could be anything , code above doesnt have anything like that , thanks